# IVS Token Authorisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda

I hope I explain a bit clearly with the problems I'm having.
I used this guide ( https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/v2/workshops/022adf04-0ff9-49af-848f-993e42575540/en-US/playauth) to generate a playback token , and after reading and following this entire guide, I was able to successfully generate a token.

```
"statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJFUzM4NCIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxm4iOiJhcm46YXdzOml2czpldS13ZXN0LTE6MDgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOmFjY2Vzcy1jb250cm9sLWFsbG93LW9yaWdpbiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmZvb3R5LnRvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ0MzUyMjI2LCJleHAiOjE2NDY5NDQyMjZ9.EQ1tnLU5uQhxnkVjJvrOo_z1Jlf4w0yMuhgWtB8ZBf_NKgWJCcMmToKia8u1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"}",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.xxxxxx.com"
  }
}
```

I put this token behind the stream url and everything works as it should work;

```
https://247dfhj3e56u467.us-xxxx-1.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-east-1.08xxxxxx06.channel.GpxxxxxxxxxxwA.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOiJFUzM4NCIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxm4iOiJhcm46YXdzOml2czpldS13ZXN0LTE6MDgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOmFjY2Vzcy1jb250cm9sLWFsbG93LW9yaWdpbiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmZvb3R5LnRvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ0MzUyMjI2LCJleHAiOjE2NDY5NDQyMjZ9.EQ1tnLU5uQhxnkVjJvrOo_z1Jlf4w0yMuhgWtB8ZBf_NKgWJCcMmToKia8u1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This token only works on my domain, and when I use it on my other domain I get a CORS error because it only works on the domain I specified in the lambda function.

So so far the token generator works...

But guess what, as soon as there are people who can take the stream link through the source code, say use this link in VLC or any other m3u8 player, even some hls/m3u8 browser extensions in chrome can play it effortlessly.

My question to you is as follows;

- Am I using the given token correctly?
- Is there perhaps a lambda function script (json) that no longer enables these playback options?
- Or can I solve this in another way so that the stream can only be played on my domain and not on a VLC player or browser extension.

Hopefully someone has a solution for this, because in this way the function of the token generator is not really valuable.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

- Your use case seems correct.
- Unfortunately, it's difficult to revoke the JWT token once you created. There is a property of expire time. Default value is 2 days in index.js and you can set shorter in case.
- If I'd do, I'd integrate with some other systems like Cognito or IP based security groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

So there is just these 2 options?
There is somewhere no lambda function to block specific user agent like VLC and/or Ace Player?
Or an http referrer function, that the link is only playable comming from my domain, this because someone is posting my stream links
somewhere and alot people using this link straight into VLC player without joining my site.

It just sucks that i need to pay money for those who never joined my site

Comment: I'm not sure this is fitting to your question but Lambda functions do not capture ip or domain. Consider using other services, maybe CloudFront and WAF. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecurityAndPrivateContent.html

Comment: You have to realize that not everyone is a developer or a scripter, for people like me this is maybe to difficult. I just pay alot more money for bandwidth by users who never joined my site. For me ivs token generator just sucks, and is useless, if people just copy the link and paste it in any player or browser extension then whats the point of the token? I also use Nimble streamer to push the stream to IVS, nimble has an option to insert some regex code so the link is not playable in VLC and ACE Player nor on any domain. This should be standard in IVS to avoid customers for huge bills!